# C# Generic extension method that accepts int, Guid and string as Id parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, repository

I am trying to create extension methods for my repositories. The entities in my project can have int, string and Guid keys.
My code looks like this:

Base Entity Interface:

```
public interface IBaseEntity<TId>
{
    TId Id { get; set; }
}
```

Extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WithId<TSource, TId>(this IQueryable<TSource> query, TId id)
    where TSource : IBaseEntity<TId>
{
    return query.Where(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

The error I get is 'Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TId' and 'TId'.
The 'ugly' solution would be to create 3 extension methods, but I would rather have it with a generic like this.

(My project runs .NET 7)

I tried implementing System.IEquatable< T >, replace < TId> in the interface with < out TId>, and inserting a BaseEntity class (that implements the interface), but all did not work.

Comment: The point about generics is that they serve for *all* types, not just three. In particular these types need to share some common behaviour, which I doubt `int` and `string` do (despite maybe the stuff inherited from `object`). You should write one method per type.

Answer (score 0):

You try can adding generic constraint for `TId` to implement [`IEquatable<TId>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-8.0) interface which will allow to use `Equals` (which is translatable by EF Core based on my tests) in your `WithId` method:

```
public interface IBaseEntity<TId> where TId : IEquatable<TId> 
{
    TId Id { get; set; }   
}

static class Exts
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> WithId<TSource, TId>(this IQueryable<TSource> query, TId id)
        where TSource : IBaseEntity<TId> where  TId : IEquatable<TId>
    {
        return query.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(id));
    }
}
```

In theory you could use `IEqualityOperators<TId, TId, bool>` but currently using static abstract interface member in expression trees is not supported (possibly it will be changed in future though - you can monitor the [[Proposal]: Expression tree evolution](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4727) @github).